# Issue with setting icon image in cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimage, reuseidentifier

I am trying to create a 'blank_star icon' in every cell of a table view, the star should become a 'solid' star after the user clicks on it.

I have created a subclass of `UIButton` as seen below

```
//.h file
@interface Bleh : UIButton {

}

+(id)specialInit;
-(void)vvv;

@end

//.m file
@implementation Bleh

+(id) specialInit
{
    Bleh* button=[super buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];    
    [button addTarget:button action:@selector(vvv)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    NSLog(@"%d",[button isEnabled]);
    return button;
}


-(void)vvv
{
    NSLog(@"button tapped");
    [self setEnabled:false];
}

@end
```

I added the subclass of UIButton in my table view's `cellforRow:` method as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    int row = indexPath.row;
    NSString *cc = [array objectAtIndex:row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        // Configure the cell...    
        Bleh *button = [Bleh specialInit];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        NSLog(@"Button:%@ at row number: %i",button, indexPath.row);

        cell.textLabel.text = cc;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    }
    return cell;
}
```

However I am getting an issue when running the app. For instance, if I click on the cell marked 'a', the star becomes solid as expected.

[image]

The strange thing is that after scrolling down, I see some other cells with the solid star as well (see cell 'e').

[image]

Can anyone help to explain why this is happening? It seems like the `state` of the cell is being re-used in other cells. How can I avoid this happening?

Comment: if you are asking iphone related question, please put iphone tag, which I believe has more reachability than ios or objective-c. Then more people will see your question..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: The [iPhone] tag should be used for questions which apply _only_ to an iPhone. This question is about iOS, and uses Objective-C; those tags are completely appropriate, and [iPhone] would not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the state of the button in a NSMutableArray and when you draw the cell you set if it is enabled or disabled based on the NSMutableArray. To change the value on the Array you should Tag the cell and make the change on your vvv selector.

```
//.h file
@interface Bleh : UIButton {
    NSMutableArray *data;
}
```

On your function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    // Configure the cell...    
    Bleh *button = [Bleh specialInit];
    [button setTag:row] // row is the id of the button
    if([data objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"ENABLED"]) [button setEnabled:TRUE];
    else [button setEnabled:FALSE];
    ...
}
```

On your vvv selector

```
-(void)vvv:(id)sender {
    if([sender isEnabled]) {
        [sender setEnabled:FALSE];
        [data replaceObjectAtIndex:[sender tag] withObject:@"DISABLED"];
    }
    else {
        [sender setEnabled:TRUE];
        [data replaceObjectAtIndex:[sender tag] withObject:@"ENABLED"];

    }
}
```

And you should init the array on your viewDidLoad, lets say for 10 cells

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        [data addObject:@"ENABLED"];
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cells ARE re-used. I had this problem once myself too.
This might be a bit more memory intensive as it doesn't delete old cells from memory, but it does make coding simpler.
One trick is to do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = indexPath.row;
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat@"Cell %i", row];
    NSString *cc = [array objectAtIndex:row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        // Configure the cell...    
        Bleh *button = [Bleh specialInit];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        NSLog(@"Button:%@ at row number: %i",button, indexPath.row);

        cell.textLabel.text = cc;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    }
```

Comment: Whit, it works but my initial 'solid star' is also replaced to become a blank star again. How can I store the state of the star icon?

Comment: You would need to keep track of this externally in a NSMutableArray or something. The way the cells work is quite tricky.